# Kerberos ticket "Expired"; Finding old, not new ticket

Tags: homebrew, kerberos, azure-data-studio

I'm trying to get Kerberos connecting to a MS SQL database on my Mac (Big Sur).  I've been following instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/enable-kerberos?view=sql-server-ver15).  My Kerberos authenticated connections used to work.  They stopped working when I tried them recently.  This *might* be due to upgrading the OS.

Per the instructions, I have an `/etc/krb5.conf` file that looks something like this:

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM
 
[realms]
DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM = {
   kdc = dc-33.domain.company.com
}
```

When I go to my terminal and run `kinit username@DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM` it prompts me for my password.  After successfully entering my password, I immediately run the `klist` command, as recommended, and I'm getting something like this:

```
Credentials cache: API:1234A5B6-7C8D-9EF0-B1F9-ED757F2418F4
        Principal: username@DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM

  Issued                Expires        Principal
Apr  5 09:02:23 2022  >>>Expired<<<  krbtgt/DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM@DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM
```

This looks like an old ticket/credential (I'm writing this April 8th) somewhere on my machine.  The old ticket is "Expired".  Why isn't the klist command retrieving the recent `kinit` credential?  What would cause this?  How can I fix it?

### Things I've tried

Naively, in the beginning of all of my Kerberos connectivity issues and before getting this error, I thought I needed to update/upgrade Kerberos.  So I installed Kerberos with `brew install krb5`.  Unfortunately, I think this just confused the OS because Kerberos was then installed in 2 locations.

I saw that the operating system might need to "know" where to find Kerberos files if it gets confused (see above bullet point).  So, I added the following lines to my `.zshrc` file.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/krb5/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/krb5/sbin:$PATH
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/krb5/lib $LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/krb5/include $CPPFLAGS"
```

These lines helped while I still had the Homebrew version of Kerberos installed, but I have since run `brew uninstall krb5` and now they don't help (see next paragraph).

I did a search in my terminal for the `krb5` folder using this command `sudo find / -name "krb5"`.  When I searched through the long list of results, I found several `krb5` folders, but none of them had `bin`, `sbin`, `lib` or `include` directories in them.  So, it seems that during the `brew uninstall krb5` command those files were removed from my system as well as the files in `/usr/local/Cellar`.

I haven't tried installing the "Prerequisites" on the [instruction page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/enable-kerberos?view=sql-server-ver15) yet, because my Kerberos used to work already in the past.  So, I'm assuming that the prerequisites should already be in place, unless they changed during my OS update.  I was hesitant to try that because of the issues the `brew install` attempt created.

### Conclusion

It's obvious the Kerberos is still installed somewhere on my machine because it will prompt me to enter my password after `kinit` and knows if the password entered is valid or not.  The credentials are "Expired" immediately after being created.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you get from `which klist` and `which kinit`? It sounds slightly like you have the macOS Heimdal 'klist' but third-party 'kinit' and they're looking at different ticket caches.

Comment: for `which klist` I get `/usr/bin/klist`. For `which kinit` I get `/usr/bin/kinit` as well.

Comment: Does the ticket go away after `kdestroy`? Does it reappear after another kinit? Does its 'issued' date change between kinits? What happens if you explicitly tell the tools to use a different cache (e.g. a file)?

Comment: After `kdestroy` and then a new `kinit`, when I call `klist` I get `klist: Cache not found: API:...`

Comment: It turns out that after all of the `install` and `uninstall` that was going on my computer needed a reboot.  During the reboot there was a lot of Mac OS updates that occurred.  Now when I run `kinit` and then `klist` my credentials look fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`install`ing and `uninstall`ing kerberos appears to have messed with some of your OS settings.  This, combined with a recent OS update probably requires a restart, if you haven't already done so.